# Выделение объекта/layout при нажатии на него Android

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, background, layout

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такой эффект (см. фото). По умолчанию, при нажатии на кнопку, такой эффект есть, но я делаю список из объектов с использованием RecyclerView, и когда использую подготовленный layout, то этого эффекта нет. Gmail же тоже использует RecyclerView

Подскажите, как это называется вообще этот эффект и как его реализовать при использовании RecyclerView
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант это в разметке вашего item в `RecyclerView` выставить атрибут:

```
android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
```

Вот небольшой пример:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_height_medium_item"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground">

...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Если вам нужна более тонкая настройка, то вам нужно ручками создать ваш `background`. Вот небольшой пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/core_black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:state_enabled="false">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
                    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/background_system1" />
                    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Суть этого кода в том, что вы прописываете на каждое состояние свои атрибуты вашей `View` внутри тега `<selector>`. В примере это `android:state_enabled="false"` и статус без предустановок (ниже) который используется во всех остальных случаях. Вы можете таких состояний прописать неограниченное кол-во. Так же их можно комбинировать, например:

```
android:state_enabled="false"
android:state_pressed="true"
```

После чего вы просто задаете это `drawable` в background вашей `View`:

```
android:background="@drawable/button_round_n7_background"
```

Comment: А что означает "?" в атрибуте?

Comment: Это системный атрибут. Значения знака вопроса я не знаю